# Git: How to find whether origin/master is equivalent of (local) master?

Tags: git, git-diff, git-fetch, git-status

`git fetch` goes over the network and fetches the latest snapshot from `origin/master` to the local host. It does not merge but just fetches the snapshot. Right after `git fetch` if we do `git status`, it will tell us whether (local) `master` is ahead or behind `origin/master`.

All I want is a git command that will just tell us whether the content of (local) `master` is the equivalent of the content of `origin/master`. Obviously, it has to go over the network to determine that but it should not print any messages about its findings (like the output of `git fetch` or any other git command) and finally, just output only `yes/true` (if equivalent) or `no/false` (if different) or something similar.

Is there any git internal commands or api's which could do this?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the following snippet of code.

```
output=`git fetch --dry-run 2>&1`

if [ "$output" != "" ]; then
    echo "***********************************************"
    echo "*                    ERROR                    *"
    echo "* Your git source directory is not up to date *"
    echo "***********************************************"
fi
```

Had a problem parsing the output of `git fetch --dry-run` but found that the console messages belong to `stderr` [Git: unable to redirect/parse the output of 'git fetch --dry-run' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146187/git-unable-to-redirect-parse-the-output-of-git-fetch-dry-run-command)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-q` flag to silence `git fetch`:

```
git fetch -q
if [ "$(git rev-parse origin/master)" == "$(git rev-parse master)" ]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```