# Git: unable to redirect/parse the output of 'git fetch --dry-run' command

Tags: git, bash, shell, io-redirection

What is special about the output message of `git fetch` command that is printed on the console? I'm not able to use `grep`, `xargs`, etc. Not able to redirect the output to a file also..

Note: I'm using `git fetch --dry-run` command

```
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ 
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ git fetch --dry-run > /tmp/1
From ssh://git.code.sf.net/p/santest/code
   9f068d0..2b9dc4e  master     -> origin/master
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ 
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ cat /tmp/1              <= no data
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$  
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ git fetch --dry-run | grep "ssh"     <= output has both lines
From ssh://git.code.sf.net/p/santest/code
   9f068d0..2b9dc4e  master     -> origin/master
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ 
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$ git --version 
git version 1.7.11.4
[sangeeth@localhost santest-code]$
```

I'm trying to parse the output of `git fetch --dry-run` command to check whether the local (`master`) branch is up-to-date with the remote (`origin/master`) branch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some of git's status output goes to `STDERR`. If you want to grep through it, merge STDERR into STDOUT like so:

```
git fetch --dry-run 2>&1 | grep ssh
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to grep through it, merge STDERR into STDOUT like so:

Or, simpler and safer:

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/15ba44f1b4c307d8b2a7810232d902720f039892/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> learned the `--porcelain` option that emits what it did in a machine-parseable format. **On stdout**!

That is neat! Safer and easier to parse, directly from stdout.

```
git fetch --porcelain
```

In your case:

```
git fetch --porcelain --dry-run | grep "ssh"
```

See [commit dd781e3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd781e3856bccd3793122f7f4e604e5a89ae517d), [commit cdc034a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdc034a0ac64363b5d603b24ea7226cef2f429e3), [commit 58afbe8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58afbe885c678c5cc6f6f83badca159871fc2cb3), [commit 5095793](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50957937f92691215492f4c62dd0a18e39f17a2e), [commit 9539638](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9539638a2bbc88717547585ae660bba3bbfaef8b), [commit 1c31764](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1c31764dda4fd4aacdcc95c4a53b8c778a2f9de2), [commit 3daf655](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3daf6558eddd2841b2eeedf1f2356cb89c7c8425), [commit 2c5691d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2c5691d6cff083ebbd9207d1b518998d448f73f9), [commit 5667141](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5667141e3b2a5a9f983882df3a3b1f481ce9be88) (10 May 2023) by [Patrick Steinhardt (`pks-t`)](https://github.com/pks-t).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 15ba44f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/15ba44f1b4c307d8b2a7810232d902720f039892), 15 May 2023)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dd781e3856bccd3793122f7f4e604e5a89ae517d): introduce machine-parseable "porcelain" output format
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>

> The output of `git-fetch` is obviously designed for consumption by users, only: we neatly columnize data, we abbreviate reference names, we print neat arrows and we don't provide information about actual object IDs that have changed.
> This makes the output format basically unusable in the context of scripted invocations of `git-fetch` that want to learn about the exact changes that the command performs.
>
> Introduce a new machine-parseable "porcelain" output format that is supposed to fix this shortcoming.
>
> This output format is intended to provide information about every reference that is about to be updated, the old object ID that the reference has been pointing to and the new object ID it will be updated to.
>
> Furthermore, the output format provides the same flags as the human-readable format to indicate basic conditions for each reference update like whether it was a fast-forward update, a branch deletion, a rejected update or others.
>
> The output format is quite simple:
>
> ```
> <flag> <old-object-id> <new-object-id> <local-reference>\n
> ```
>
> We assume two conditions which are generally true:
>
> - The old and new object IDs have fixed known widths and cannot contain spaces.
> - References cannot contain newlines.
>
> With these assumptions, the output format becomes unambiguously parseable.
>
> Furthermore, given that this output is designed to be consumed by scripts, the machine-readable data is printed to stdout instead of stderr like the human-readable output is.
> This is mostly done so that other data printed to stderr, like error messages or progress meters, don't interfere with the parseable data.
>
> A notable ommission here is that the output format does not include the remote from which a reference was fetched, which might be important information especially in the context of multi-remote fetches.
> But as such a format would require us to print the remote for every single reference update due to parallelizable fetches it feels wasteful for the most likely usecase, which is when fetching from a single remote.
>
> In a similar spirit, a second restriction is that this cannot be used with `--recurse-submodules`.
> This is because any reference updates would be ambiguous without also printing the repository in which the update happens.
>
> Considering that both multi-remote and submodule fetches are user-facing features, using them in conjunction with `--porcelain` that is intended for scripting purposes is likely not going to be useful in the majority of cases.
> With that in mind these restrictions feel acceptable.
> If usecases for either of these come up in the future though it is easy enough to add a new "porcelain-v2" format that adds this information.

`fetch-options` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd781e3856bccd3793122f7f4e604e5a89ae517d/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L81-L87):

> ### `--porcelain`
>
> Print the output to standard output in an easy-to-parse format for
> scripts. See section OUTPUT in [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) for details.
>
> This is incompatible with `--recurse-submodules=[yes|on-demand]` and takes
> precedence over the `fetch.output` config option.

`git fetch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dd781e3856bccd3793122f7f4e604e5a89ae517d/Documentation/git-fetch.txt#L207-L215):

> When using `--porcelain`, the output format is intended to be
> machine-parseable. In contrast to the human-readable output formats it
> thus prints to standard output instead of standard error. Each line is
> of the form:
>
> ```
> <flag> <old-object-id> <new-object-id> <local-reference>
> ```